# Generate Swift API from WSDL

Tags: swift, wcf, wsdl, ksoap

hi i am new swift programmer , in android for wcf web service I use ksoap2.jar and it's work fine but in swift I can't find anything ((some sites is that generate wcf but one site is [objective c](http://wsdl2objc.com/) and [other site](http://gen4swift.com) get all of my method void))
 How can I generate my wcf , or library like ksoap in swift

[MY WCF](http://37.255.192.166:2036/WcfTelegram.WCF_Telegram.svc)

Comment: Have you tried GitHub ? E.g: https://github.com/banjun/WSDL2Swift

Comment: yes but its not working in android I set dotnet = true and set namespace but its not have

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. You asked for a Swift library, not Android. I assumed it was for iOS/macOS/Linux.

Comment: yes I want swift library , I said that before I start ios , i wrote in android and in android  set dotnet = true and .. but in WSDL2Swift doesn't exist this properies

Comment: @nathan It not showing executable file, after download git source code and run into My Mac WSDL2Swift I expect the executable file where i can pass the wsdl url. and convertor type.  Like previous WSDL2Obj-C.  Is it same thing like previous WSDL2Obj? where user can convert wsdl to objective-C or javascript.

Comment: I'm afraid, this wsdl2swift is not maintained anymore: 
error: SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. (in target 'WSDL2Swift' from project 'WSDL2Swift')